# How have you found Markdown for writers/editors working on articles?

Tags: cms, text-editor, markdown

I am a web developer putting together a system for writers/editors to efficiently add — fairly rich — content to a website.

I've previously used standard WYSIWYG editors but find that often what you see isn't what you get. I've seen this lead to frustration and bad code.

Has anyone implemented Markdown to write articles? If so, how did you find it? I like the idea of saving articles in markdown as it keep HTML separated from the content.

Comment: Please don't cross post **exactly** the same question to multiple sites.